# Yup/formik number validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have an input with id="rate" and validation set up in the following manner:

```
validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
  rate: Yup.number('Rate A')
    .required('Rate B')
    .positive('Rate C')
    .moreThan(0, 'Rate X')
    .integer('Rate Y')
    .typeError('Rate Z'),
```

If I fill in anything in the `rate` field, the validation will pass, including strings.

The only time the validation fails is if I leave the field completely blank - I get `Rate X` meaning that it didn't pass the "more than 0" rule.

If I am not supplying enough information please let me know, though I honestly don't know if there's anything that is relevant that I've left out.

Comment: What is your Question?